# How does Irelia counter Jayce?

Tags: league-of-legends

Everyone says Irelia is a counter to Jayce but i've played the matchup 3 times, twice as Irelia, once as Jayce and everytime Jayce came out ahead easily.

Yes, at level 6 Irelia on even gold can go 1v1 against Jayce... but every game Jayce was already far ahead at that point.

The two times i played as Irelia, Jayce combo'd me at level 2 with Cannon Q, Hammer Q, Hammer E for almost half my health and then forced me back under tower with his Cannon Q at which point i lost a ton of CS since every time i tried to get a minion Jayce shot me for more than my health gain from W and every time i tried to attack him directly i got hit by Hammer QWE and was lucky to get out alive.

The first time i started with Regrowth Pendant + Potion, the second time with Cloth Armor + 5 potions, didn't make any difference.

At level 6 i burst him with my ult and forced him out of lane for a short time but at that point i was already 30cs behind and when he came back with new items he completely trashed me without me even having a chance to run away.

When i played Jayce against Irelia it was basically the same situation with me beating her at every stage and when she hit 6 i was already snowballing hard and beat her 1v1 with 75% health remaining.

I mostly follow this guide, going QWE and then maxing W->Q->E:
http://www.lolpro.com/guides/irelia/74-irelia-guide-top-lane

My opponents seem to be going QEW and then maxing E->Q->W

What is the point i am missing?
It must be something very simple and i'm just too blind to see the obvious but i just can't see Irelia winning this matchup.

Comment: @Ender I like this question a lot more because it's providing a specific problem and asking for a tangible solution. "Who counters  Jayce" could be asking for 1-liners or a whole essay on every Jayce vs X matchup.

Comment: @BBz Ender was not specifically saying that they are duplicates, he was simply pointing out a question that may also have interesting and realevant information for people viewing this question.

Comment: I have now expanded the information in my answer to the linked question to answer this one as well.

Comment: related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77555/15095

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**----"It must be something very simple and I'm just too blind to see the obvious but I just can't see Irelia winning this matchup."**

Don't worry. I don't see it either.

Irelia isn't the best counter versus Jayce. I highly recommend Yorick. He's actually extremely powerful top lane right now, as you might have noticed on the forums when people have asked, "How do I counter ____ top?" - "Yorick. 'nuff said." Other good counters I have found from personal experience include

- Cho'Gath
- Rumble
- Malphite
- Nautilus
- Vladimir

Why? Because they have a lot more sustain than jayce, and can set up very good ganks with a jungler because of their kits. In addition, they have nice harass while Jayce's harass is skill-shot based, so it is avoidable.

And finally, Viktor. If you haven't read Jayce's lore, read it. WHO DARES QUESTION SCIENCE

**----But I want to play as Irelia!**

And so here are some tips on how to 'counter' Jayce, because otherwise this would be a pretty off topic answer.

First of all, make sure you have a point in all of your abilities. I tend to go Equilibrium Strike first, in case I get into a fight early or if their jungler ganks before I hit level 2, I can easily stun and get out. Then, I get Bladesurge at level 2, getting Hiten Style and levels 3, 4, and 5 to maximize my healing.

- **Try to play safe and passively until about level 5.** Wait for Jayce to get your hp down just a little bit lower than his, then **BLADESURGE ONTO HIS FACE**, hit Equilibrium Strike, and start going at him with your Hiten Style. The reason I suggest level 5 is because Jayce is ranged, and unfortunately, you're not. If you Bladesurge onto him at earlier levels, minions can hurt. A lot.

**----Note** Know how much damage your Bladesurge will do to him. It does 20/50/80 +1.0 Attack Damage, so make sure after you Bladesurge that his health won't be lower than yours, or else you'll be left with a measly slow or be forced to wait until he gets his health higher.

- Remember how I suggested some champions to counter Jayce because they could set up good ganks with a jungler? Well, Irelia can do that too with Equilibrium Strike. Again, wait for your health to be just a bit lower than Jayce's, stun him, and work together with your jungler to pick up the he kill.

**----Note** Usually, especially in higher levels of play, the jungler is supposed to make the first move in order not to arouse too much suspicion. However, if you can, make the first move by using Equilibrium Strike to stun Jayce first, so that the jungler has time to close the gap in between the river and wherever Jayce is. However, it's still situational. If you and Jayce are both at low health, it might be best for the jungler to go in first.

- **Don't push too hard.** Irelia is great at getting high creep score with her Bladesurge as well as the healing and extra true damage from Hiten Style. I find that her kit makes it easy to get CS under the tower. Note that Irelia can push fairly hard, so make sure you're not overextending, making you prone to jungler ganks. You're a melee champion, and Jayce can safely kite you at his tower until later levels.
- Buy what counters Jayce and the rest of his team; **Do not always follow exactly what the LolPro build says**. It's a reference, kind of like a note card when you're giving a speech.
- **Dodge his shock blast**, especially when fired through acceleration gate. The 40% increased damage hurts a lot, and could constantly send you back to base, putting you behind.

  - Regrowth Pendant can be good for recovering after being hit by one of those bad boys, but I personally like to **run Boots of Speed and Health Potions**. Why? Because it helps me dodge Shock Blast. It's kind of common sense, but, when Jayce puts an acceleration gate right in front of your face, he's probably going to shoot a Shock Blast through it so try to predict him, and dodge it, or even **Bladesurge a minion** to avoid it.

I've compiled Jayce and Irelia's stats and compared them to see who scales better. The better stat at level 5 is in **bold**.

**Jayce vs. Irelia**

- Health 420 (+90) ---- **456 (+90)**
- Attack Damage 46 (+3.5) ---- **56 (+3.3)**
- Health Regen 6 (+0.8) ---- **7.5 (+.65)**
- Attack Speed .658(+3.0%) ---- **.665(+3.2%)**
- Mana **240 (+40)** ---- 230 (+35)
- Armor 12.5 (+3.5) ---- **15 (+3.75)**
- Mana Regen **7 (+.7)** ---- 7 (+.65)
- Magic Resist 30 ---- **30 (+1.25)**

Good luck beating Jayce with Irelia! :)

**----** Credibility of this Answer - League of Legends player for two years, and I own both Jayce and Irelia with experience with both champions, more notably Irelia. I have also won top lane using the alternative champions I suggested at the very top.

Champion stats found on leagueoflegends.wikia.com

Comment: This is a good answer and i'm tending to accept it though i'll wait a while to give others a chance before i do so.

Comment: @Ezreal This is very well written answer. Good job

Comment: Very good answer, and the additional counters you mentioned are useful.

Answer (score 1):

She outscales him and does decent in lane against him. You can sneak CS with your Q, you can get 2 GoldPerTen - Items and you will outscale him. 
If you have a strong jungler with good CC, you can set up ganks pretty easily as well.

EDIT: to clarify: I am saying Irelia does not beat Jayce. She just can FARM against him (most top laners cant do this). So if you want to play against Jayce and you are fine just outscaling him, go for Irelia and do what I wrote at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Irelia has the sustain Jayce hasn't. You never should go agressive on him at early levels, try to farm safely and keep up with the farm. Consider maxing E over Q for the burst and if he lets u initiate without using q. SO basically you come with w-e-aa, then he knocks u back and u Q in again.

Answer (score 0):

Irelia does in fact counter Jayce.  I play at the 1950 elo level.

Irelia can actually trade with hayce as soon as level 1.  People dont' understand why irelia is so strong, it's that E.  once level 2 hits, there's not many champions who can withstand your e w.  Now obviously jayce has a knockback, which means you can't just walk up to him and start smacking with hiten style.  However,you really should understand Jayce's cooldowns.  If jayce uses his hammer e on you, both his crossbow and e are on cooldown.  You are irelia, you have a gap closer.  This is why you win.  Use minions in order to get close and reset your q.  bring the fight to him, but dont overchase.  Remember you can HARASS FOR FREE as irelia.  You zoom to a minion, e, activate w, and smack him twice.  At that point he will be out of stun.  Now back off.  most likely he will counter with more harrass.  If he was in hammer, that means he has to switch to poke you.  Well guess what?  Your hiten style is still active and so is your q.  Now you dash back after baiting him more towards the center of the minion line, and you chuke with a q buffed by w.  Now you also get off an auto attack.  You'll be amazed how much damage that combo does.  Usually q on the last tick of hiten style is really how you gib most top lanes.

Best of luck.  And remember, your cloth armor approach doesn't work because jayce's e in hammer form is an atk dmg scaling magic dmg ability.